# sybase interactive sql initialization error (java path)

Tags: sybase, sap-iq

Getting this error, from the looks of which it's a missing classpath.
Trying to force the classpath via setting it like below doesn't help.

set CLASSPATH=C:\Sybase\Shared\SAPJRE-8_1_008_64BIT\lib

This is a relatively fresh installation of Sybase IQ, and I'm trying to run the Interactive SQL from the program list.

```
C:\Sybase\IQ-16_1\Bin64>dbisql.com
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
[Last 4000 events in the event buffer]
  <thread>                      <time>  <id>          <description>
 23548                            0.00  0x00000001    Creating red and yellow zone [0x0000008890e00000,0x0000008890e04000]
Aborting  ...
```

Curious if there's a way to debug it through an elevated verbose level - to see which class is not being found. Very odd that a new installation would do that. Windows 10 environment, compatible with IQ 16.x

Comment: I'm not familiar with `dbisql.com`, but a general question not addressed by the OP ... was `${SYBASE}/SYBASE.sh` sourced before trying to use `dbisql.com`?

Comment: Correct, ran the batch to set the environment before the execution. Dbisql call followed suit using the command line. No luck so far. Any chance you could share your Sybase-related Unix environment, maybe I could deduce what is missing.

Comment: sorry, my Sybase environments are based around ASE, SRS and DA (I don't have an IQ environment at this time), and I use (non-java) `isql`

Answer (score 1):

I do not recognize that exactly error, but had others jvm issues with Sybase Interactive SQL, changing the JVM path in dbisql.ini fixed it (ini file located in same folder as dbisql.com).

That type of error seems to be related with incorrect java assumptions. Until java 8 objects in JVM were packed a certain wait that changes on 9.

Alternatively one can use another database cliente software.